# How can I set the FTP prompt?

Tags: ftp, prompt

I using Ubuntu 18.04 from WSL and using the default Ubuntu FTP client.
The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tnftp.1.html) mentions setting `$FTPPROMPT` which I have done in my `.bashrc` on my local machine and then sourced that file.

```
$ echo $FTPPROMPT
%n:%n:%/
```

Yet this does not seem to have any effect on the prompt that is shown. I still get the uninformative `ftp>`.

How can I set options for `ftp` that actually work?

(FTP server is ProFTPD and logs in with csh)

Comment: Have you already connected to the ftp server at this point?

Comment: Is the `FTPPROMPT` variable exported?

Comment: The man page you are linking appears to be for the `tnftp` ("enhanced ftp client") implementation - which Ubuntu ftp package did you actually install? the implementation from the vanilla `ftp` package for example likely doesn't support those prompt options.